# Update generated page in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I want to create application that will be similar to wikipedia but for specific topic. I decided to use nuxtjs because of it speed and how easy I can create some views.
Problem is at generating static pages. Not all rendered pages need to be generate, lets assume some moderator updated page and want to save it. How could I make generate process for only 1 updated page and replace this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the problem is you are facing, do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve and how it currently looks like? If you are just looking for some tips, have you had a look at the content module of nuxtjs? https://content.nuxtjs.org/ . Or a headless CMS like https://www.storyblok.com/ ?

Comment: I want to run script ```npm run generate``` that will only generate html files for these which need to be updated, due to large structure of possible files I want to prevent generating all of them like this is going by default.

Comment: Like this? https://nuxtjs.org/blog/nuxt-static-improvements/#generate-time-cache-vs-full-webpack-build

Comment: Yeah, something like this. Thanks I will test this solution